# Kippo Honey statup failure

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, open-source

When I try to start my installed kippo honey using `./start.sh`, it shows following error.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use code formatting.

Comment: Install the correct version of `twisted` using `pip2`.

Comment: What is the version have to install on there?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below to run Kippo and Kippo-Graph on ubuntu 18.04 and later to this time.

1. Install dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install build-essential python-mysqldb apache2 python-dev libmysqlclient-dev python-virtualenv python-pip mysql-server mysql-client libapache2-mod-php php-cli php-common php-cgi php-mysql php-gd php-xml php-curl php-gmp php-bcmath
   ```
2. Set up mysql to work with kippo playlog:

   2a. Use the code below to create and open disable_strict_mode.cnf in the editor:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/mysql/conf.d/disable_strict_mode.cnf
   ```

   2b. Copy and paste this code into the editor and save it and exit the editor:

   ```
   sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
   ```
3. Start the mysql server:

   ```
   sudo service mysql start
   ```

   OR restart it if it is already started:

   ```
   sudo service mysql restart
   ```
4. Login to mysql server:

   ```
   sudo mysql -u root -p
   ```
5. Run the code below (one line at a time) to create the database and user for Kippo:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE kippo;
   GRANT ALL ON kippo.* TO 'kippo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'kippo';
   exit
   ```
6. Run the code below (one line at a time) to create a user for kippo in Ubuntu:

   ```
   sudo useradd -m kippo
   sudo passwd kippo
   ```
7. Exit sudo user with `exit` and login with kippo user:
8. Run the code below (one line at a time) to set up Kippo:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/desaster/kippo
   cd kippo/doc/sql
   mysql -u kippo -p
   USE kippo
   source mysql.sql;
   show tables;
   exit
   cd ..
   cd ..
   cp kippo.cfg.dist kippo.cfg
   ```
9. Run the command below and uncomment mysql and add kippo mysql user as *kippo* and password as *kippo* and save and exit the editor:

   ```
   nano kippo.cfg
   ```
10. Run the commands below (one line at a time) to create a python virtual environment and prepare it to run Kippo:

    ```
    cd
    virtualenv kippo_env
    . ./kippo_env/bin/activate
    pip install twisted==15.1.0
    pip install pyasn1
    pip install pycrypto
    pip install MySQL-python
    cd kippo/
    ```
11. Run Kippo on port 2222 by default:

    ```
    ./start.sh /home/kippo/kippo_env/
    ```
12. Run the commands below (one line at a time) to install Kippo-Graph *optional:

    ```
    cd /var/www/html
    sudo wget http://bruteforcelab.com/wp-content/uploads/kippo-graph-1.5.1.tar.gz
    sudo tar zxvf kippo-graph-1.5.1.tar.gz
    sudo rm kippo-graph-1.5.1.tar.gz
    sudo mv kippo-graph-1.5.1 kippo-graph
    cd kippo-graph
    sudo chmod 777 generated-graphs
    sudo cp config.php.dist config.php
    ```
13. Run the command below to edit the Kippo-Graph configuration file and fill in mysql host, Kippo user as *kippo* and password as *kippo* and other options if required:

    ```
    sudo nano config.php
    ```
14. Run the command below to run apache server:

    ```
    sudo service apache2 start
    ```

Done. Kippo-Graph can be accessed at http://localhost/kippo-graph/